# Simple Python IDE that supports multiple tabs and a Python shell?

Tags: python, ide

I have been trying to pick a good IDE for Python and stick to it.

I looked at this question as well [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) which lists lots of IDEs, but doesn't tell whether they have the features I am after or not.

I tried Sublime Text and Atom. I was able to get a Python shell on Sublime Text, but that doesn't work sometimes. In Atom, I tried to hack it by adding a package called REPL Term, but that throws an error. PyCharm on the other hand looks heavy and expensive.

So, I was really looking for an IDE with three features:

1. Being able to display multiple files at once as tabs.
2. Having a Python shell where you can load a script
3. Possibly displaying a file tree.

Comment: Someone marked my question as duplicate, but obviously he didn't read my entire question as I already explained that the question he is referring to doesn't actually answer my question. That question doesn't tell whether those IDEs support a Python shell or not.

Comment: pycharm community edition is free

Comment: But, it doesn't support Python for web development as they say. I need to do some Flask applications.

Comment: I've gotten django to work with pydev (so python plugin for eclipse)...which is obviously free